# Can't update Mozilla Firefox

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, firefox

I am using

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

and my firefox is

```
~$ firefox -v

(process:2709): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 30.0
```

But when I try to update it, it doesn't work, even though I think my version is pretty old. What am I doing wrong?

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
viktor@viktor-ThinkPad-T520:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10 came out over 3 years ago, and only had 9 months of software updates and support. It reached "end-of-life" status in mid-2014. (See https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases ). Since your Ubuntu version is no longer supported at all by Canonical, new versions of Firefox are not made available for your system. You'll need to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 (or 16.10) in order to receive ongoing security and software updates.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version

to try and update Firefox - I think that will be another useful way to solve this little problem.
That link describes the way to (manually) update Firefox much better than I could do - but anyway … I'll try and give an explanation by myself:
If you choose Help > About Firefox in it's menu, there should be displayed a button giving the possibility to update FF manually if there is really an update available. 
In other words: if there is none available at the time, the button won't be displayed.
As far as I remember, Firefox should even display a message mentioning an available update by itself - if there really *is* one available.
I was on Ubuntu 8.04 on another computer, so the package management on that machine did not work anymore - but I got a rather new Firefox from somewhere else, and was able to update it the way I described before.

Comment: Please expand on your answer, as posting a link is not really helpful.  A little step by step that the OP and others can follow would be ideal :)

Comment: This doesn't work, I just tested it with a Vivid VM and it's stuck with 44 while the latest version currently is 50.